# Javascript three.js smooth camera motion

Tags: javascript, three.js

In javascript, I can use the `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){...});` to add a key listener. However, when using `three.js` and moving the camera with the key, the camera moves once, delays, and then continues moving. This is because the computer delays key holding for a fixed amount of time. How would I go about making the camera move smoothly when the key is pressed?

Comment: Try starting a continuous movement on keydown, and halting on keyup. That's a general way to do hold inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting a continuous movement on keydown, and halting on keyup. That's a general way to do hold inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer. It helps that you didn't limit the possibilities with code, and gave me a general idea of how to do it. Very useful.